# Zoom In/Out in eclipse Oxygen in Code Editing WITH ABAP/SAP-Plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abap

I'm using **eclipse Version Oxygen** with **ABAP/SAP Plugins**.

I want to **zoom in/out** my code. 
But this does **NOT work with the ABAP Plugins**.
Without the ABAP Plugins, I can zoom in/out normally.

Has anyone a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: it works with eclipse Neon WITH ABAP Tools. Probably we just have to wait for an update ^^

Comment: You are right. You can edit font size if you want. :)

Comment: Can you post screenshots of where it does not work for people who don't have those tools?

Comment: @nitind 

http://imgur.com/a/PESht
Here are my installed Plugins :)

Comment: That's not really what I asked for. Where, once installed, does it not work? Can you show that?